# Grouping median by day of week

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to group the median response time on conversations by weekday

This is what I got so far, but it does not group correctly (multiple entries for each app_id, each with it's own value of the response time. Instead these should be grouped into one, and only display the median)

Any ideas?

```
select
    c.app_id,
    case when extract(dow from c.first_response_at) = 1 then percentile_cont(0.5) within group ( order by c.response) else 0 end as mon,
    case when extract(dow from c.first_response_at) = 2 then percentile_cont(0.5) within group ( order by c.response) else 0 end as tue,
    case when extract(dow from c.first_response_at) = 3 then percentile_cont(0.5) within group ( order by c.response) else 0 end as wed,
    case when extract(dow from c.first_response_at) = 4 then percentile_cont(0.5) within group ( order by c.response) else 0 end as thu,
    case when extract(dow from c.first_response_at) = 5 then percentile_cont(0.5) within group ( order by c.response) else 0 end as fri,
    case when extract(dow from c.first_response_at) = 6 then percentile_cont(0.5) within group ( order by c.response) else 0 end as sat,
    case when extract(dow from c.first_response_at) = 7 then percentile_cont(0.5) within group ( order by c.response) else 0 end as sun
from
(
with t(app_id, response, first_response_at, updated_at) as (
    select app_id, extract(epoch from (first_response_at - started_at)) as response_time, first_response_at, c.updated_at
    from apps a
    left join conversations c on c.app_id = a.id
    order by c.updated_at desc
)
select app_id, response, first_response_at, updated_at
from t
) as c
group by c.app_id, c.first_response_at, c.updated_at
order by c.updated_at desc
```

Comment: Are you sure you need the `, c.first_response_at, c.updated_at` in `group by`?

Comment: Yes because I use them in the select state to extract the dow

Comment: But then you get one row per `c.app_id, c.first_response_at, c.updated_at` combination. IMHO `extract(dow from c.first_response_at)` should be in `group by`

Comment: Yeaj bit How can I avoid that?

Comment: Use Gordon's `PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY CASE WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM c.first_response_at) = 1 THEN c.response END)` and `group by c.app_id` only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#1: You need to move the `CASE` into `PERCENTILE_CONT` as proposed by Gordon Linoff.

#2: remove `, c.first_response_at, c.updated_at` from `group by`

#3: order by `min` or `max(c.updated_at)`

#4: no need for a nested CTE/Order By

#5: move the `Extract(dow)` into the Deried Table

```
select
    c.app_id,
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY CASE WHEN dow = 1 THEN c.response end) as mon,
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY CASE WHEN dow = 2 THEN c.response end) as tue,
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY CASE WHEN dow = 3 THEN c.response end) as wed,
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY CASE WHEN dow = 4 THEN c.response end) as thu,
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY CASE WHEN dow = 5 THEN c.response end) as fri,
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY CASE WHEN dow = 6 THEN c.response end) as sat,
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY CASE WHEN dow = 7 THEN c.response end) as sun
from
 (
   select app_id,
       extract(epoch from (first_response_at - started_at)) as response_time, 
       EXTRACT(dow FROM c.first_response_at) as dow,
       c.updated_at
   from apps a
   left join conversations c on c.app_id = a.id
 ) as c
group by c.app_id
order by max(c.updated_at) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

`percentile_cont()` should ignore `NULL` values.  So, you want to move the day-of-week condition *inside* the function call:

```
with t(app_id, response, first_response_at, updated_at) as (
       select app_id, extract(epoch from (first_response_at - started_at)) as response_time, first_response_at, c.updated_at
       from apps a left join
            conversations c
            on c.app_id = a.id
      )
select c.app_id,
       percentile_cont(0.5) within group
           (order by (case when extract(dow from c.first_response_at) = 1 then c.response end)) as mon,
       . . .
from t
group by c.app_id, c.first_response_at, c.updated_at
order by c.updated_at desc;
```

EDIT:

Hmmm, I should the above would work.  But, a `filter` may be more appropriate:

```
select c.app_id,
       percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by c.response)
           filter (where extract(dow from c.first_response_at) = 1) as mon,
. . .
```

Comment: Still doesnt work, now I just get a bunch of null values